# Issue finding calculation for sidebar and content area that respects one side of a container

Tags: html, css

I've drawn up a handy dandy image of what I've been trying to do with CSS. Ideally, I'd like to do this with ONLY CSS, but at this point I would be OK with a JS solution.

[image: Sidebar Calculation]

Essentially, the sidebar on the left would not respect the header grid of 1200px, centered. It will always be 1/3 of the viewport. The content area needs to bump up against this sidebar on the left, but it needs to stop once it reaches the edge of the header container on the right.

I've tried calculating the viewport minus 1200px, minus 600px, and several other calculations, trying to get this content area to shrink and grow correctly, but I am at a loss on how to go about it.

My last idea was to try to get that ??% area in the picture calculated somehow so I could push the content area over, but I'm not sure how to grab it.

Here's a pen of where I left off: https://codepen.io/WDACDavy/pen/LJrxmY

Here's the accompanying HTML and CSS:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: #FF570c;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

aside {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #dddddd;
  width: 33.3333%;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 66.6666%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.strange-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <section>
      <div class="strange-container">&nbsp;</div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Ok, so the accepted answer turned out to not be 100% what I needed. For those of you curious or who need a similar layout, this is what I did:

I took the accepted answer's calculation (which was great!) and turned it into a padding-left for the `<section>` element.

```
padding-left: calc((100vw/3 - (50vw - 600px)));
```

Then I added a gradient to the `<main>` element to give the sidebar its background and added an absolutely positioned `<aside>` for the sidebar content. End result is here: https://codepen.io/WDACDavy/pen/KxemLm

This will work until the screen gets down to near 1200px (which is fine for my use case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation of this area should be `100vw/3 - (100vw - 1200px)/2` [width of the sidebar minus the space on the left of the header] . You can use it as a negative `margin-left` then add a `margin-right` equal to `(100vw - 1200px)/2` [the space on the right of the header]. You need to pay attention as the caclucation may not be accurate when you have scrollbar.

I removed the scrollbar to see the result:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: #FF570c;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:1200px;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

aside {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #dddddd;
  width: 33.3333%;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  width: 66.6666%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.strange-container {
  display: block;
  margin-left:calc(-1 * (100vw/3 - (50vw - 600px)));
  margin-right:calc(50vw - 600px);
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.8);
  flex: none;
}
/*We no more have space around section so we replace it by 0*/
@media all and (max-width:1200px) {
  .strange-container {
    margin-left:calc(-100vw/3);
    margin-right:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <aside>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div class="strange-container">&nbsp;</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work on wide screens (1920px or so).

Comment: @DavyH there is an extra max-width in your section that you need to remove

Comment: Ayy. Thank you very much for this! I'll mark as the correct answer.